# Bootstrap Tiles Grid - 4th tile hangs

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having an issue with a grid of tiles for a our blog

http://benefacto.org/blog/

On view ports above 1024 the 4 tile ends up on a line of its own.

This doesn't happen if I change the height of the tiles #blog-tile from min-height: 448px to height:600px, but then it upsets the proportions on smaller view ports.

Is there anyway I can maintain the responsive heights without throwing the grid system> Many thanks,
Ben

Comment: You have `#blog-title` repeated ID which is crime.

Comment: You need to calculate the heights correctly and do the math right. Increasing `min-height` does work. There's one component, which doesn't follow the right height.

Comment: Hi @PraveenKumar thanks for your help. Could you explain a bit better about doing the maths right?

Comment: And why is repeating #blog-title a crime?

Comment: "repeating #blog-title a crime"  mean you cannot have same id for more than one element. Id represent unique html element. You can use class instead.

Comment: Id is a seprate it can use only one time but you can use class is multiple time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a solution for you:

your `.blog-main` will need these styles:

```
.blog-main {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 3%;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    float: left !important;
}
```

It currently looks like this:

```
.blog-main {
    padding: 3%;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    float: left !important;
}
```

That way it will work as you expected.

This works because the `flex` technology will make sure the horizontal alignment is equal between all your div's.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is genius!